# How to simplify a javascript function into clean readable code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

here i have created a function , it is framing a object by getting two values as arguments. It is working fine. But in the code wise is not simple. It is not readable. Here i am sharing the code of what i have done. Please suggest me where i have to modify the code. In order to make it more clear and readable.

```
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';

const questionsObject = {};
const finalDndDataFormat = {};

let value = [{"groups":[{"notes":"","questions":[{"name":"loanAmount"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"loanReason"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"email","type":"email"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"title","required":true}]},{"questions":[{"name":"firstName"},{"name":"lastName"}]}],"id":"my-needs"},{"groups":[{"questions":[{"name":"phone"},{"name":"isCellPhone"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"dateOfBirth","options":[]}]},{"questions":[{"name":"residenceStatus","options":[],"label":"q_ownRent_text","type":"radio","required":true}]},{"questions":[{"name":"addressLine1"},{"name":"addressLine2"},{"name":"city"},{"name":"province","options":[]},{"name":"postalCode"}],"title":"q2_supporting_2"},{"questions":[{"name":"employmentStatus","options":[]}]}],"id":"a-bit-about-me"},{"groups":[{"questions":[{"name":"residenceDuration","options":[]}]},{"questions":[{"name":"previousAddressLine1"},{"name":"previousAddressLine2"},{"name":"previousCity"},{"name":"previousProvince"},{"name":"previousPostalCode"}],"title":"q2_supporting_2"},{"questions":[{"name":"previousResidenceDuration"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"residenceStatus"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"principalResidence"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"residenceType"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"propertyValue"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"monthlyMortgagePayments"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"mortgageBalance"}]}],"id":"my-home"},{"groups":[{"questions":[{"name":"employmentDuration"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"previousEmploymentDuration"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"paycheckAmount"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"paycheckFrequency"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"hasAdditionalIncome"},{"name":"additionalIncomeSource"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"hasChildTaxCredit"},{"name":"childTaxCreditMonthlyAmount"},{"name":"numberOfDependentsChildTaxCredit"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"sinNumber"}]}],"id":"my-income"},{"groups":[{"questions":[{"name":"hasPaydayLoan","options":[]},{"name":"paydayLoanAmountOwing"}]},{"questions":[{"name":"hasOtherLiabilities","options":[]},{"name":"otherLiabilitySource","options":[]}]},{"questions":[{"name":"isEasyHomeCustomer","options":[]},{"name":"easyhomePaymentsLiabilityMonthlyAmount"}]}],"id":"liabilities"},{"groups":[{"notes":"","questions":[{"name":"agreeTermsConditionsAndPrivacyPolicy","options":[],"links":[]}]}],"id":"t-and-c"}]
let appPages = ["my-needs", "a-bit-about-me", "my-home", "my-income", "liabilities", "t-and-c"]

const setDndDataStructure = (value, appPages) => {
 
    const dndFormat = value?.map((data) => {
        appPages.forEach((pages) => {
            switch (data?.id) {
                case pages:
                    const questions = data?.groups || {};
                    questions.map((obj) => {
                        obj.id = uuid();
                        const uniqueQuestionName = obj?.questions?.map((questionsField) => questionsField?.name);
                        obj.unique = uniqueQuestionName[0];
                    });
                    const dndDataFormat = { [pages]: { name: pages, items: questions } };
                    Object.assign(questionsObject, dndDataFormat);
                    Object.assign(finalDndDataFormat, questionsObject);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
    return finalDndDataFormat;
};

setDndDataStructure( value , appPages )
```

**Result:**

```
{"my-needs":{"name":"my-needs","items":[{"notes":"","questions":[{"name":"loanAmount"}],"id":"1b356c8f-0087-4929-8894-2a929aa25c6c","unique":"loanAmount"},{"questions":[{"name":"loanReason"}],"id":"59a57164-d945-4747-a429-763a38da61d5","unique":"loanReason"},{"questions":[{"name":"email","type":"email"}],"id":"d526fb2f-8612-4313-a4be-b1779817ccd2","unique":"email"},{"questions":[{"name":"title","required":true}],"id":"420028a5-a280-4fb4-96f6-a3fa464ad531","unique":"title"},{"questions":[{"name":"firstName"},{"name":"lastName"}],"id":"fe2f12e9-5c66-4b6b-ab82-ec7d3fe50226","unique":"firstName"}]},"a-bit-about-me":{"name":"a-bit-about-me","items":[{"questions":[{"name":"phone"},{"name":"isCellPhone"}],"id":"d74a5ba2-30a8-473b-8db9-bf82b3f2a6e9","unique":"phone"},{"questions":[{"name":"dateOfBirth","options":[]}],"id":"86ae162d-beb7-4f1a-a74b-c161515f3144","unique":"dateOfBirth"},{"questions":[{"name":"residenceStatus","options":[],"label":"q_ownRent_text","type":"radio","required":true}],"id":"0e5b151d-46f8-460d-862a-3e75aa6438df","unique":"residenceStatus"},{"questions":[{"name":"addressLine1"},{"name":"addressLine2"},{"name":"city"},{"name":"province","options":[]},{"name":"postalCode"}],"title":"q2_supporting_2","id":"31120f92-771d-4136-b465-ad7abf944718","unique":"addressLine1"},{"questions":[{"name":"employmentStatus","options":[]}],"id":"03796c7b-7ff9-4abb-9fe3-f01db45de4f3","unique":"employmentStatus"}]},"my-home":{"name":"my-home","items":[{"questions":[{"name":"residenceDuration","options":[]}],"id":"65ce7da7-005e-4f62-ba5a-0768afa01111","unique":"residenceDuration"},{"questions":[{"name":"previousAddressLine1"},{"name":"previousAddressLine2"},{"name":"previousCity"},{"name":"previousProvince"},{"name":"previousPostalCode"}],"title":"q2_supporting_2","id":"e9682e67-8e03-4ffd-b695-a8bc50dca98d","unique":"previousAddressLine1"},{"questions":[{"name":"previousResidenceDuration"}],"id":"f473e302-469b-4196-aa1a-00da1bdb4cf6","unique":"previousResidenceDuration"},{"questions":[{"name":"residenceStatus"}],"id":"c3f4f424-9619-458f-9e20-343247835ecd","unique":"residenceStatus"},{"questions":[{"name":"principalResidence"}],"id":"6c6d9aa8-e693-40f4-b805-b1333c6e97f1","unique":"principalResidence"},{"questions":[{"name":"residenceType"}],"id":"1946d5fd-86ae-4c18-aeb6-7f03d2cfc3e1","unique":"residenceType"},{"questions":[{"name":"propertyValue"}],"id":"27ed276a-e42c-4a9a-923e-fdf953ef4e56","unique":"propertyValue"},{"questions":[{"name":"monthlyMortgagePayments"}],"id":"38b306c2-4328-4c10-9281-e736348c4047","unique":"monthlyMortgagePayments"},{"questions":[{"name":"mortgageBalance"}],"id":"b67b7f19-caef-4404-9592-0c4293d92c4d","unique":"mortgageBalance"}]},"my-income":{"name":"my-income","items":[{"questions":[{"name":"employmentDuration"}],"id":"ad78527d-c5d9-42f3-879e-79c78c10c72d","unique":"employmentDuration"},{"questions":[{"name":"previousEmploymentDuration"}],"id":"596d9c81-5549-4e98-935d-faf65cd91b8d","unique":"previousEmploymentDuration"},{"questions":[{"name":"paycheckAmount"}],"id":"076827a0-1e77-4455-bfb5-d0d7c59fd34c","unique":"paycheckAmount"},{"questions":[{"name":"paycheckFrequency"}],"id":"709704d6-5451-4fcb-93d1-c11090d789b4","unique":"paycheckFrequency"},{"questions":[{"name":"hasAdditionalIncome"},{"name":"additionalIncomeSource"}],"id":"a17cde6c-6a3f-4792-bfc6-bafa2237cf1c","unique":"hasAdditionalIncome"},{"questions":[{"name":"hasChildTaxCredit"},{"name":"childTaxCreditMonthlyAmount"},{"name":"numberOfDependentsChildTaxCredit"}],"id":"a138e279-712b-4e0a-9adb-30c4b89f754f","unique":"hasChildTaxCredit"},{"questions":[{"name":"sinNumber"}],"id":"ab5e04ac-3cd7-431f-adbf-a63ecf410af0","unique":"sinNumber"}]},"liabilities":{"name":"liabilities","items":[{"questions":[{"name":"hasPaydayLoan","options":[]},{"name":"paydayLoanAmountOwing"}],"id":"6aedc455-1204-4dfb-8f76-97c4bdc0b66b","unique":"hasPaydayLoan"},{"questions":[{"name":"hasOtherLiabilities","options":[]},{"name":"otherLiabilitySource","options":[]}],"id":"fda26736-db4f-4a38-b122-dd6a898be9df","unique":"hasOtherLiabilities"},{"questions":[{"name":"isEasyHomeCustomer","options":[]},{"name":"easyhomePaymentsLiabilityMonthlyAmount"}],"id":"fda94364-9b90-4a93-80ac-698415a5207d","unique":"isEasyHomeCustomer"}]},"t-and-c":{"name":"t-and-c","items":[{"notes":"","questions":[{"name":"agreeTermsConditionsAndPrivacyPolicy","options":[],"links":[]}],"id":"b7c74dce-1251-4831-8066-65cb73a598c7","unique":"agreeTermsConditionsAndPrivacyPolicy"}]}}
```

Above code is the sample i have done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just add a few comments

```
//At the end, setDnDStructure will leave x structured as y
const setDndDataStructure = (value, appPages) => {
 
    const dndFormat = value?.map((data) => { // mapping x to y so that z
        appPages.forEach((pages) => {
            switch (data?.id) {
                case pages:
                    const questions = data?.groups || {};
                    questions.map((obj) => {
                        obj.id = uuid();
                        const uniqueQuestionName = obj?.questions?.map((questionsField) => questionsField?.name);
                        obj.unique = uniqueQuestionName[0];
                    });
                    const dndDataFormat = { [pages]: { name: pages, items: questions } };
                    Object.assign(questionsObject, dndDataFormat);
                    Object.assign(finalDndDataFormat, questionsObject);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
    return finalDndDataFormat;
};
```

The comments I've added should give you an idea of how you can make this more readable. Outline what you are trying to achieve at the end, and use comments in your function to outline what each step is doing